# How to generate RSA1 signature from file with a passphrase

Tags: ruby, openssl, rsa, digital-signature

I need to generate  a RSA1 signature for a string  using file with a passphrase
ex:

```
require "openssl"
pri = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new( File.read("cert.prv" ) )
string = 'Some string'
sign = pri.sign( "sha1", string.force_encoding("utf-8") )

 puts sign
```

cert.prv file has a passphrase `123456` if I run this script from console I input this passphrase by hand...
But if this is run from a script how can I pass passphrase to `OpenSSL` ?

Comment: What does "RSA1" mean? "RSA-x" is usually written where "x" is the bit size of the modulus. A modulus of 1 bit doesn't permit *any* RSA operation. What is the "1" supposed to mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the passphrase while opening the file.

```
pri = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read("cert.prv"), '123456')
```